# Difference between pointer to array and reference to array

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

```cpp
int arr[10]{};

int* ptr = arr;   // legal
int* (&ref) = arr;   // illegal
```

While pointer and reference are just same when it comes to assembly,
it is a bit hard for me to understand that `int* ptr` can points to array while `int* (&ref)` has to define it as `const` or explicitly show size such `int (&ref)[10] = arr`

What is the difference?

Comment: good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: `int* decay = arr; int (*ptr)[10] = &arr; int(&ref)[10] = arr;`.

Comment: `ptr` is just a thing pointing at the first element of the 10 element array `arr`.  `ref` is illegal because you are trying to create a reference to the wrong type of thing (@Jarod42 identifies that for you).  Try [c++decl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/c++decl) for decoding / explaining strange declarations.   And the article @Alessandro Teruzzi points to covers all the stuff you need to know about refs.